# What defines whether a movie is considered standalone or ensemble in regards to character copyrights?

Tags: copyright

Marvel owns the rights to the Hulk character but the distributing rights belong to Universal. This prevents Marvel from releasing a standalone Hulk movie without the go ahead of Universal or paying out of their own pocket, so they've decided to get around this by including Hulk in the Thor movies. But what constitutes a Hulk movie? Is it screentime?

Comment: What does the contract between the companies define a "standalone Hulk movie" to be? Nobody is going to answer this question without that knowledge, and I firmly doubt anybody with the knowledge is going to share it.

Answer (score 1):

This would be dealt with in the terms of the Universal-Marvel contract. Since this is a commercial contract its terms will be private to the parties unless and until they are ventilated in a courtroom to settle a dispute. That says, I would guess the contract has a binding arbitration clause so disputes will never see the inside of a courtroom anyway.